# I want to fetch complete mail header from inbox using IMAP

Tags: php

I am using IMAP to fetch mails from an inbox, Now I want to fetch complete header of a particular mail, Which IMAP function should I use to fetch all the header informations ?

I checked php.net and found many to grab header info, Could you please specify one to get complete header info

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit a "fetch" command, specifying "body[header]"

Like this:
A01 fetch 88 body[header]

A01 is a unique identifier
88 is the message number

Cheers!